# I hold A,Q,10 of spades in Bridge hand. What is probability that my partner holds K and J of spades?

Tags: probability

Since I hold 3 spades and 10 non spades there are 10 outstanding spades and $(26-10)= 16$ non spades outstanding. I calculated ${10\choose 2}\cdot{16\choose 11}/{26\choose 13}$ giving $0.0188981$. I do not think this is correct but I have been unable to come up with a better method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Where does $26$ come from? There are $52$ cards in the bridge deck. 2. Your question is not completely clear. Do you mean that your partner spades are *exactly* AQT or he may hold AQTxx in spades? Do you wish to find the probability that your spades are *exactly* KJ or you just want KJ to land at your hand?

Comment: "my partner holds K and J of spades". Does that mean that he holds no other spades?

Comment: @drhab, usually no. But judging by the given "solution", seems so.

Answer (score 1):

I preassume that "holds K and J of spades" means also that these are the only spades in the hand of the partner.

There are $39=2+8+29$ cards that are *not* in your hand. The $2$ stands for the spades $K$ and $J$, the $8$ for the remaining spades and the $29$ for the non-spades. Think of your partner picking $13$ cards out of these $39$ cards. Then the probability that he ends up with $K$ and $J$ of spades and $11$ non-spades is: $$\frac{\binom22\binom80\binom{29}{11}}{\binom{39}{13}}$$

Of course you can simplify this expression.

---

If my preassumption is wrong then we split up in $39=2+37$ cards and come to a probability of:$$\frac{\binom22\binom{37}{11}}{\binom{39}{13}}$$